# B+Tree implementation, confusion about class pointers in C++

Tags: c++, treenode, b-tree

I have to `code` an implementation of a `B+Tree` for a project and have some trouble.

There are 2 `classes`, one is the `Leaf`, which saves *data*, and a `class`  named `Node` (contains *data* and `pointers` to leafs). `Classes` contain more `members`, `prev*`, `next*` and so on... also `methods`.

To keep it simple:

```
Node
{
   values[];
   Leaf*[];
};


Leaf
{
   values[];
};
```

Problem is, `nodes` only can save `pointers` to Leafs, but what I want is that they can also save `pointers` to `nodes` (for the above layer). If the Leafs full, it has to split up.
Insert a `value` in the above `node`. Also if the `node` is full, it splits up, and if no parent `node`, it creates one. And so on. Splits can propagate through the full *tree*.

Is there an easy way around this? Having a `class` with which can handle different types of `array pointers`  in multiple instances? Do I have to use *templetes* and *polymorphism*?

Comment: Do you need to use a `Leaf` class in the first place ?

Comment: Class Node can have a member `Node*` What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I think the main reason for your being stuck is the `Leaf` class. A leaf is just a node without children.

Comment: Only use node class where a leaf is just a node with no children.

Comment: also you can extend (leaf is a kind of node)